# Compile error Xcode 4.3.1 ->OpenCv Framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, opencv

i've tried to install `openCV` using `MAcPort`, but i retrieve some errors. So i downloaded the framework folder an i added it to xcode link libraries. Now when i write my code and i build it i retrieve this error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Volumes/OpenCV2.0/OpenCV.framework/OpenCV, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvCreateCameraCapture", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvQueryFrame", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvGetSize", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvCreateImage", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvCvtColor", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvShowImage", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvWaitKey", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvDestroyAllWindows", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvReleaseImage", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_cvCreateHist", referenced from:
      _create_histogram_image in main.o
  "_cvGetMinMaxHistValue", referenced from:
      _create_histogram_image in main.o
  "_cvConvertScale", referenced from:
      _create_histogram_image in main.o
  "_cvSet", referenced from:
      _create_histogram_image in main.o
  "_cvGetReal1D", referenced from:
      _create_histogram_image in main.o
  "_cvRectangle", referenced from:
      _create_histogram_image in main.o
  "_cvReleaseHist", referenced from:
      _create_histogram_image in main.o
  "_cvCalcArrHist", referenced from:
      _cvCalcHist in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Have anyone had the same error? can you help me??? thanks !!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to link a 64-bit application with a 32-bit framework.

Comment: I think it is due to the GCC version being used as mentioned by lifesayko below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the GCC 4.2 compiler?
XCode4 uses LLVM by default, and openCV isn't compatible with it (yet).
To check click on the Project, go to Build Settings, search for "compiler".

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem as mentioned by JackTurky using opencv 2.4.2 installed from macports on Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion. I tried changing the default compiler from Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 to LLVM GCC 4.2 but then other problems appeared in relation to @autoreleasepool and ARC and general objective c syntax. Fortunately, I had  an Xcode project that was originally built using Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard that still worked with my current setup. I carefully compared the build settings of the working and the broken project. So, using the Apple LLVM compiler 4.1  and going to build settings -> Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 language -> C++ Standard Library, I changed from libc++ (...) to libstdc++ (..) and all the errors vanish when you build your project again. Works for me, hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for you :).. I am struggling from last 3 days on that topic, and it is solved by changing libc++ to libstdc++ , THanks

Comment: HI Grrphon... How to change libc++ to libstdc++ and where is the option to change.. Please guide me @Gryphon

Comment: @Babul go to build setting, and type standard Library in search bar, and change the C++ standard Library option. libc++ to libstdc==

Comment: I already try all options below but still got error:

ld: warning: ignoring file ./opencv2.framework/opencv2, missing required architecture x86_64 in file ./opencv2.framework/opencv2 (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvLoadImage", referenced from:
      _main in main.o

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try this one instead:

http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/face-tracking/

Copy the framework directly and then just add this in your prefix.pch

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

It should work very easily.