# missing required architecture x86_64 in file opencv

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, opencv

experts:

I am trying to create a C++ framework using Xcode.  My framework depends on OpenCV.  I am having the same issue as other have had to deal with.  I found a likely answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729158/compile-error-xcode-4-3-1-opencv-framework) but when I try to copy the following code into my Prefix.pch file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

I get this error when I try to build:  **'OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found**

Now, I know that it is because I'm using the opencv2.framework.  So my question is:

***"How do I reference that in my Prefix.pch file?"***

Thank you for your help,
Lucy

-------------------------------------------------- **More Info** -----------------------------------------

I tried to add the framework but that isn't working.  Is there something else I need to do?

[image: Header Search Paths]

[image: OpenCV Dir]

[image: Files in Headers]

[image: Prefix.pch]

[image: Frameworks]

Comment: Is OpenCV setup in you header include path in the build settings?

Comment: Where is the header include path in the build settings?  I see a Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths and a Private and Public Headers Folder Path.  How do I include OpenCV in my header include path in the build settings?

Comment: That is what I meant, make sure the Header Search Paths includes the directory that the root OpenCV header is located in.

Comment: I tried to add the framework, but I must not be doing it correctly.

Comment: @Joe - Is there anything you can see?  In my Prefix.pch file, I am importing <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>.  I think this is the problem, but I don't know how to import it from a framework.

Comment: OK.  I got past the error on the import line by changing the path.  Now, I'm getting this error:  (null): Ignoring file /Users/pdl/Development/proj/opencv2.framework/opencv2, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/pdl/Development/proj/opencv2.framework/opencv2 (3 slices).  Does OpenCV need to be built with the same architecture?

Comment: All the examples look easy and I've done everything they tell you to do.  Could it be because I am creating a framework not an application?

Comment: I commented out all code using OpenCV and this is the error I received (in sections, because it's too long:


Ld /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tfp-gcadehxhpanobrgyqerfrgygapyp/Build/Products/Debug/tfp.framework/Versions/A/tfp normal x86_64
    cd /Users/pdl/Development/tfp/tfp
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tfp-gcadehxhpanobrgyqerfrgygapyp/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tfp-gcadehxhpanobrgyqerfrgygapyp/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/pdl/Development/tfp/tfp -filelist

Comment: /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tfp-gcadehxhpanobrgyqerfrgygapyp/Build/Intermediates/tfp.build/Debug/tfp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/tfp.LinkFileList -install_name @executable_path/../Frameworks/tfp.framework/Versions/A/tfp -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -framework opencv2 -framework Cocoa -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker

Comment: /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tfp-gcadehxhpanobrgyqerfrgygapyp/Build/Intermediates/tfp.build/Debug/tfp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/tfp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tfp-gcadehxhpanobrgyqerfrgygapyp/Build/Products/Debug/tfp.framework/Versions/A/tfp

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/pdl/Development/tfp/tfp/opencv2.framework/opencv2, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/pdl/Development/tfp/tfp/opencv2.framework/opencv2 (3 slices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was compiling to 64-bit and OpenCV does not support that.  Maybe because of cross architecture support.  We changed to Universal (32/64-bit) and that seemed to make it work.  There were a few more Xcode configurations that needed to be tweaked but that was the reason for the error.

Comment: Can you detail more how you solved the issue? I had the same, and I solved it selecting ``Standard Architectures`` under Build Settings. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you are correct.  It's been awhile since I looked at this and I think the Universal (32/64-bit) terminology was coming from the fact that we were creating an Aggregate Target.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option (which happened to me) is that you have accidentally downloaded the wrong OpenCV framework. For example you might have downloaded the iOS one in which case the correct architecture wont exist for your mac. Make sure to download and then extract the right version from the opencv website to a unique folder.